# Changing else-if code to something cleaner

Tags: java, if-statement

I have following else-if code and I am really getting annoying with a size of the lines needed for it, so I was thinking if there is some more appropriate way to do it which will be more cleaner and more faster?

```
if (dialogResult == 0) {
            System.out.println("Yes option to try again!");
            if (level.equals(lp.LEVEL1.getLevelName())) {
                System.out.println(lp.LEVEL1.getLevelName());
                level = lp.LEVEL2.getLevelName(); // set level
                totalBall = lp.LEVEL2.getBallCount();
                numberOfExplodes = lp.LEVEL2.getBallExplosion();

            } else if (level.equals(lp.LEVEL2.getLevelName())) {
                System.out.println(lp.LEVEL2.getLevelName());
                level = lp.LEVEL3.getLevelName(); // set level
                totalBall = lp.LEVEL3.getBallCount();
                numberOfExplodes = lp.LEVEL3.getBallExplosion();

            } else if (level.equals(lp.LEVEL3.getLevelName())) {
                System.out.println(lp.LEVEL3.getLevelName());
                level = lp.LEVEL4.getLevelName(); // set level
                totalBall = lp.LEVEL4.getBallCount();
                numberOfExplodes = lp.LEVEL4.getBallExplosion();

            } else if (level.equals(lp.LEVEL4.getLevelName())) {
                System.out.println(lp.LEVEL4.getLevelName());
                level = lp.LEVEL5.getLevelName(); // set level
                totalBall = lp.LEVEL5.getBallCount();
                numberOfExplodes = lp.LEVEL5.getBallExplosion();

            } else if (level.equals(lp.LEVEL5.getLevelName())) {
                System.out.println(lp.LEVEL5.getLevelName());
                level = lp.LEVEL6.getLevelName(); // set level
                totalBall = lp.LEVEL6.getBallCount();
                numberOfExplodes = lp.LEVEL6.getBallExplosion();

            } else if (level.equals(lp.LEVEL6.getLevelName())) {
                System.out.println(lp.LEVEL6.getLevelName());
                level = lp.LEVEL7.getLevelName(); // set level
                totalBall = lp.LEVEL7.getBallCount();
                numberOfExplodes = lp.LEVEL7.getBallExplosion();

            } else if (level.equals(lp.LEVEL7.getLevelName())) {
                System.out.println(lp.LEVEL7.getLevelName());
                level = lp.LEVEL8.getLevelName(); // set level
                totalBall = lp.LEVEL8.getBallCount();
                numberOfExplodes = lp.LEVEL8.getBallExplosion();

            } else if (level.equals(lp.LEVEL8.getLevelName())) {
                System.out.println(lp.LEVEL8.getLevelName());
                level = lp.LEVEL9.getLevelName(); // set level
                totalBall = lp.LEVEL9.getBallCount();
                numberOfExplodes = lp.LEVEL9.getBallExplosion();

            }
            ...
```

I was thinking switch could go fine here, but I would like to hear other options as well.

UPDATE: This is my class: lp is of class Balls which is enum and has 3 params in it's constructor:

```
public enum BallCount {

    LEVEL1(5,1,"Level 1"),
    LEVEL2(10,2,"Level 2"),
    LEVEL3(15,4,"Level 3");
```

Comment: switch will be more readable option. Anyway somewhere you have to compare it

Comment: Instead of `lp.LEVEL1`, `lp.LEVEL2`, etc., you could greatly simplify your code by using an array `lp.LEVELS` and just looping through them. Also, this probably belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sorry, that's not how StackOverflow works.  This is not a discussion forum. Please visit the [help] and read [ask]

Comment: you can put the objects in array, determine which level is "on" and take value out of array arrordingly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Great advice. @TedHopp

Comment: It would be hard to answer you, wherever you post this, if you don't show what all those LEVEL values are. Is that an enum? Plain constants of a certain object type? Why are you keeping your level as a string if you have objects for the levels? Not enough information here.

Comment: Level is a String value from Enum field. I was thinking to put it into for(if) loop but I can't figure out how. @RealSkeptic

Comment: A switch would be a bit cleaner. Beyond that you should really take a good look at the repetitious nature of the code in the `if` blocks. That can be changed into a method very easily.

Comment: Can you post its code, rather than a description of the code?

Comment: I have done it. @RealSkeptic

Answer (score 0):

Make `LEVEL1, LEVEL2, LEVEL3....` or `lp' to implement following method:

```
/**
 * Gets Level enum from name.
 */    
public static Level getLevelFromName(String);

/**
 * Gets next level. 
 * Each level may either keeps reference to the next level or 
 * using enum cardinal number can get the next number.
 */
public Level getNextLevel();
```

Then your if-then gets reduced to following one/two liner with no conditions.

```
Level nextLevel = Level.getLevelFromName(level).getNextLevel();
level = lp.LEVEL6.getLevelName(); // set level
totalBall = lp.LEVEL6.getBallCount();
numberOfExplodes = lp.LEVEL6.getBallExplosion();
```

Comment: No type name in Java should use UPPERCASE. That includes enums.

Comment: Making the code a method would be ideal. `foo(lp.levelX, lp.levelY);` once you know which one.

Comment: I agree. Somehow LEVEL felt better to imply a enum that defines LEVEL1, LEVEL2,...as it looks more symmetrical. Btw those are just conventions.

Answer (score -2):

You can replace the conditional with polymorphism.
Basically, it means that you move the implementation in the if blocks into the same function on each of the objects. Then, just invoke the function, and the right code will run.

You can take a look at https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism for a more thorough explanation.

Comment: While this answer may be useful please take a look at [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). I realize that this wasn't link-*only* but it was close.